# "groups" is no valid input at this position

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I recently updated the MySQL Workbench from 5.7 to 8.0 and started to face this error in my SQL scripts:

[image]

And I remember it was working just fine on older version of Workbench. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) document on 8.0 version the word `groups` is a reserved keyword and in order to make this create statement work i had to quote that keyword like:

```
create table `groups` (
  id                bigint          AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  title             nvarchar(100),
  description       nvarchar(500),
  visibility        int,
  keywords          nvarchar(200),
  score             bigint          default 0,
  isDeleted         boolean         default false,
  addedBy           bigint          not null,
  lastModifiedBy    bigint          not null,
  addedOn           timestamp       not null default current_timestamp,
  lastModifiedOn    timestamp       not null default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp
);
```